# How to compare a timestamp with string date in Firebird 2.5?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

This updates nothing, even though it does have this date.

```sql
UPDATE inventario_setor SET data_fechamento = NULL 
WHERE DATA_FECHAMENTO  =  CAST('2022-06-08 11:26:45' AS timestamp)
```

`data_fechamento` is a `timestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

The code as you show will work just fine, **if** the value actually would be `2022-06-08 11:26:45`. More likely, it has a sub-second component that you ignored (or your query tool doesn't display; try to select it with `cast(DATA_FECHAMENTO as varchar(50)`).

To illustrate this:

```sql
create table datetime_test (
  id integer primary key,
  datetime timestamp
);
```

```sql
insert into datetime_test (id, datetime) values (1, timestamp '2022-06-08 11:26:45');
insert into datetime_test (id, datetime) values (2, timestamp '2022-06-08 11:26:45.1234');
```

Now:

```sql
select id, datetime 
from datetime_test 
where datetime = CAST('2022-06-08 11:26:45' AS timestamp);
```

will only return the row with id = 1.

So, to fix this issue, you either need to put in the exact timestamp value, or you need to use a range:

```sql
DATA_FECHAMENTO between timestamp '2022-06-08 11:26:45' and timestamp '2022-06-08 11:26:45.9999'
```

Another possible problem - but less likely - would be that you have an index on `DATA_FECHAMENTO` and that this index is somehow corrupted, so the row cannot be found.

You could detect that if the following query does not return a row

```sql
select *
from inventario_setor
WHERE DATA_FECHAMENTO = CAST('2022-06-08 11:26:45' AS timestamp)
```

and the following does return a row (adding 0 will cause the index not to be used)

```sql
select *
from inventario_setor
WHERE DATA_FECHAMENTO + 0 = CAST('2022-06-08 11:26:45' AS timestamp)
```

In that case, if you are SYSDBA (or connected with role RDB$ADMIN), you should be able to rebuild the index with

```sql
alter index <index-name> active;
```